# Delete App in iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, iphone

I add a new app in iTunes Connect, but can't delete it in any case because no `Delete` button in `Additional Information` section.
 what I got from the [iTunes Connect Developer Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html) is :

> If the Delete App button isn’t displayed, check that you’re the team agent and that the app is in one of the statuses that allow the app to be deleted.

but I'm team agent, and the app status is `Prepare for Submission`.
Now is `2016-02-20`, so, guys, have you solve it so far?

Comment: don't worry wait a minute .

Comment: mickey your app is in review state or prepare state ?

Comment: Dipen has solve my question, thanks. : )

Comment: Now you can delete even if not submitted https://stackoverflow.com/a/52682672/5306470

Answer (score 1):

You mention that **"I add a new app in iTunes Connect"** `You can delete your app if there is at least one approved version of the app` and the latest version status is one of the following:

1. Prepare for Submission
2. Invalid Binary
3. Developer Rejected
4. Rejected
5. Metadata Rejected
6. Developer Removed From Sale
7. Removed from Sale

if your app has a different status, you can delete the app by first rejecting the build or by removing the app from sale.

Read iTunes connect Developer Guide carefully [iTunes Connect Developer Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html)

Comment: Ah, Thanks Dipen, I'll be more careful, :)

Comment: You answer is wrong. Now i have rejected application but i can not delete this...

Comment: @Genevios did you check iTunes connect developer guide ? please check it in provided link in my answer.

Comment: Understand question first, And then after arguments with me. Go with posted link in my answer and search "Deleting an App" you get the answer.

Comment: @DipenChudasama Friend i am so sorry, it's my big fault, user must be admin and have juridique privilège